# Alien crashed and stuck underwater, trying to communicate with humans for help

Tags: story-identification

I will try you for another that has been bugging me for a very long time.

It is set on a beach down in Mexico somewhere, I think, and its about an alien that has been in a crashed spaceship for a very, very long time under the water, can communicate in very vague ways with near by humans by giving them images or nightmares, and just wants to die. So there are ghost type stories in the area. I think it is finally understood by a diver who moves enough material it can be exposed to a sunrise so it can get its wish. The story would have been in an issue of Asimov's or *Analog*, or maybe even *Fantasy & SF*, likely back in the '80s or '90s or so, as I was getting all of those back then.

Comment: Clifford D Simak's [*The Thing in the Stone*](http://speculiction.blogspot.com/2014/04/review-of-thing-in-stone-by-clifford.html)  has a similar theme but nothing else matches.

Comment: I'm thinking of a story I read about a spacewrecked alien traped underwater, who communicates with some nearby people through their dog. The people think there's something strangely wrong with their dog, and their is, it's controlled telepathically by an alien. Any chance that could be the same story?

Comment: @user14111 : no, that's Theodore Sturgeon's *Tiny and the monster* (1947). The alien can only move underwater, but doesn't want to die -- it wants to escape, and is helped to do so.

Comment: @lserni Yes!! "Tiny and the Monster", that's the one I was trying to remember. Thanks!